# Wordpress Automated Movies Updates

Tags: wordpress, movies

I have to develop a site like this (http://flippa.com/auctions/2673302/site) where I have to show the last films and films information that I'm getting from IMdb.. there are a few APIs I can use to make the code and retrieving posters, videos, etc, but I would like some ideas about how can I add it to Wordpress! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The two ways I can think of are: Add the IMDB functionality to your theme's `functions.php` (easy, but won't stand the test of time) or make a plugin.

Personally, I would make this into a plugin. [Here's the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) on writing Wordpress plugins. You can put all your IMDB-interfacing code in the plugin, then use a combination of hooks and template tags to expose the goodies to your theme. All of that is explained in detail in the documentation. In fact, Wordpress has fantastic documentation so I suggest slapping [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) on your favorites.